# save date from datepicker immediately on user click

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to capture the user date immediately on user selection on datepicker widget (inline version).  Can you point me in the right direction?

```
HTML
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">

JS
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true,
    onSelect: function(){
      var selected = $(this).val();
      // log to check if date is being saved, which its not
      console.log(selected);
    }      
}).datepicker('update', new Date());
```

Here's a link to the codepen as well:
http://codepen.io/cmicpace/pen/xVdMWE?editors=1011

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onSelect is a jQueryUI function meanwhile you are using bootstrap datepicker in the example.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

use `$("#datepicker").datepikcer().on("changeDate", function(e))`

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Answer (score 0):

Are you using boostrap or Jquery datePicker? 
**update()** method is not valid method for Jquery datePicker. So, I believe you use Bootstrap datepicker. 
Bootstrap datepicker fires 'changeDate' event soon after the date changed by user selection. Here is example for you to pick the date based on 'changeDate' event.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({         
        autoclose: true,               
  }).datepicker('update', new Date(2016, 2, 5)).on('changeDate', dateChanged);              
});

function dateChanged(ev) {       
      console.log(ev.date);
}
```

Update method carries only below argument. So, new Date() is not valid argument.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', new Date(2011, 2, 5));
```